# expo-app-auth' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21

Tags: kotlin, authentication, build, expo, eas

I received the below error when trying to build my project from my expo-app-auth/android/build.grandle. how to clear this error when building? I think I've tried almost all solutions found online.

```
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
AAR for react-native-reanimated has been found
/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-71-hermes.aar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.

The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:

project ':expo-app-auth' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.



  repositories {
    maven {
      url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
  }

  dependencies {
  
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.21")
  }
}

apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue could be fixed by upgrading from expo 48 to expo 49.

To upgrade the project run these two commands:

1. `npm install expo@^49.0.6`
2. `npx expo install --fix`

The second command is important because it will auomatically upgrade react-native from 0.71.* to 0.72.*

See [the official docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/#:%7E:text=49.0.0,0.19.6) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Is it possible to upgrade from expo 47 straight to 49 ?

Comment: Yes it's possible by doing the same steps. I don't know if there will be side effects.

Comment: thank you. but im getting another error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by upgrding from expo 48 to expo 49

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Resolving Expo-app-auth Dependency Error**

This error occurs due to the expo-app-auth dependency being deprecated.

**How ​​to solve:**

1. Access the node_modules folder, locate the **expo-app-auth** folder and
   remove it;
2. Open the **package.json** file and delete the mentioned dependency;
3. Then run **yarn** or **npm install** to install or remove dependencies.

**Note**: If the problem persists and the dependency is still in package.json, repeat the steps above, but this time check if you have other libraries, packages or dependencies that use **expo-app-auth** . If so, also remove those packages, as they may also be (possibly) deprecated.

Comment: Good day, thank you so much for your feedback, I removed the expo-app-auth folder and the error message has been removed. I did remove other dependencies and it seems all good. Only issue is now the below error Im receiving:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr] 

* What went wrong:

[stderr] 

Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

[stderr] 

> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1